# [UIImageView _cleanUpCrossView], problem on iPad

Tags: iphone, image, view, iad

need help here. i have an app that completely works on iPhone (ios 4) and iPod touch. but when i try on iPad i got this Log error message :

**-[UIImageView _cleanUpCrossView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e7760
CoreAnimation: ignoring exception:-[UIImageView _cleanUpCrossView]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x2e7760**

app is still running but cannot be clicked at all, it stucked at that page. i try to googled anywhere, but no result.

any help would greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in iOS 3.2.  Can you tell more about how you triggered it?  For me, it happened to be called on a custom titleView of the navigationItem (in your case, using a UIImageView) when I tried -hidesBackButton:animated.